# Merge Two tables in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables(Tabl_A and Table_B) in Excel as shown in the following figure. I want to merge them so that output is like the third table (Tabl_C).

[image]

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: You can probably use powerquery to merge join these tables on Sections as key then remove the repeated Sections column.

Comment: Cross-posted at:
http://www.msofficeforums.com/excel/40230-how-merge-two-tables-excel.html, 
https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?9350-How-to-Merge-Two-tables-in-excel, & https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1069234-how-merge-two-tables-excel.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184